# TargetFrameworkMoniker for .NET CF applications

Tags: .net-cf-3.5

I'm trying to workout what the TargetFrameworkMoniker would be for .NET 3.5 CF applications, i.e. what the assembly thinks it's been compiled under.

I've had a look on-line and around the Assembly class but can't find anything to give me some pointers of where to look. I know this is a .NET 4.0 addition so does this mean it's not possible to inspect previous assemblies? - I know NuGet seems to do it, but it appears to use the "Project" class, which is tied into VS2010 projects.

Any help appreciated thanks!